# SSH+SVN issue with the software "Versions"

Tags: ssh, svn, port

Anyone ever have this issue?

To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
An unknown Subversion error occurred. (code = 210002)

Comment: What do you mean by '"Versions"' in the title?

Comment: @ptman, Versions is a Subversion client for OSX http://versionsapp.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do when it throws that error? Can you perform the same action at the command line? A bit more info might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had this issue before.  Without more information, it's hard to produce a solid answer.  The best answer I can give is to edit your config file and look for the tunnels section and look for a line similar to this:

```
    [tunnels]
    tunnelName=/usr/bin/ssh -p 2000 -l user
```

Remove the -q option from whatever entry is in the tunnels list.  This should allow you to better debug the problem and provide more information about the cause.

Additionally, here is a resource on SSH Subversion configuration:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s03.html#svn-ch-6-sect-3.4